# Indexed with lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I have a project in lucene 4 and inside of project there is a directory structure where index are stored. Indexs have a field that it refer to one unique identifier of integer type. My question is how can I do to get last document inserted in any index with all its information, if exist some method in lucene that do it.

Answer (score 0):

lucene is not there method ,you can add a timestamp field for remember insert time , only this , you can query lastest document and through order timestamp desc .

Comment: so can you show me how to do this that you explain me?